# Best practices to follow for non transactional DB calls with Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-transactions

I was developing an application with @Transactional annotation on Spring service class. To access db layer, I have AbstractDao class which return current session when needed. i.e

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected Session getSession() {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}

public List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion criterion) {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.add(criterion);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

I am thinking of removing transnational support as I really don't need it and I want to improve the performance of db calls as I have to support many number of db inserts per second.

1) Is it OK to use non transnational db operations with Hibernate and Spring?

2) So how can I change above code to support non transaction?
 Can I create above code as follows?

```
private Session session;
protected Session getSession() {
    if (session == null) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

So createEntityCriteria() can call getSession() get session. So we can manage one session per user request (HTTP spring MVC request) with above code.

If it is OK then should I close session at the end of user request?  So if there are 300 MVC user requests per second then it will open 300 JDBC calls to the DB ( as sessionFactory.openSession() create a new JDBC call).

Comment: You're not required to use transactions, but you should be cautious here.  Transactions are useful, maybe a bit of reading is in order. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html

Answer (score 0):

Creating transactions are not an expensive operation and so wrapping a method call that performs a read-only operation won't gain you much in the way of performance under most typical application usage.

But anytime the application plans to alter data for any particular reason, it should be wrapped inside a transaction, particularly if you're altering multiple tables, such as changing an entity relationship, etc.  This makes sure that the multiple SQL statements are batched together and are only visible to other sessions at commit time of all changes and not before.  This is critical to maintain database integrity.

Insertion performance often relies more heavily on other factors beyond whether you're creating a transaction such as whether you chose to use an `IDENTITY`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, or `SEQUENCE` primary key versus a natural key and/or whether you set the proper JDBC batch size.

Furthermore, a web-based application will likely suffer far more performance headache in the web framework handling code than you will with being concerned about whether you're using a transaction or not :).

Regarding JDBC calls, this is again where a connection pool is useful.

It only hands out a specified maximum number of connections to the application and once that cap is reached, further requests for connections can either be told to wait a number of seconds in hopes a connection comes available or immediately throw an exception, allowing the application to handle it as needed.